# Show 1 is not contained in the ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Given the ideal I = $(x^2- x - 1)$ in the ring $\Bbb Z_3$[X]. Show that $1$ is not contained and hence show that the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_3$[X]/$(x^2 - x - 1)$ is not the zero ring.

I don't really know what to do. I feel like I'm overthinking this massively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition,
$$I = \{ f \cdot (x^2 - x - 1) \mid f \in \Bbb Z_3[x] \}.$$
So, if $1 \in I$, then there must be an $f \in \Bbb Z_3[x]$ such that
$$1 = f \cdot (x^2 - x - 1).$$
Now look at the degrees left and right.

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought, guess I was just being an idiot and overthinking

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but...If 1 were in the ideal then 1 = $f(x^2 - x - 1).$ However, there is an extension of $Z_3$ such that $(x^2 - x - 1)$ completely splits in that field extension. Then you would get 1 = 0.